# How use Google's Geocode API with batches of addresses

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, apply, google-geocoder

I am trying to start with a list of addresses, call Google's Geocode API, and return the corresponding longitude and latitude for each address. So far this is what I have:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd`
#List of addresses and make dataframe
address1=['100 20th St. Seattle WA','300 Main St. Washington DC','100 Main 
St Richmond VA 23220']`

address1=pd.DataFrame(address1,columns=['Address'])`
#Set up API key
api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
api_response = 
requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= 
{0}&key={1}'.format(address1, api_key))
api_response_dict = api_response.json()`

#create function for calling API
def get_long_lat(address):
  if api_response_dict['status'] == 'OK':
   latitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
   longitude = api_response_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location'] 
   ['lng']
   return latitude, longitude `

#attempts a passing the dataframe through the function 

address1['attempt1']=address1.apply(get_long_lat,axis=1)
address1['attempt2'] = address1.apply(lambda x: get_long_lat(x),axis=1)
address1['attempt3']= address1.groupby('Address').apply(get_long_lat)
address1['attempt4']=address1['Address'].apply(get_long_lat)`
```

[image: output image]

I'm trying to call the function row by row but the problem is that it's returning the long and lat for the first address and copying it for the other addresses. Is this a problem with using a pandas dataframe or the `.apply` function or maybe an API thing?

Comment: I take it the backticks in the code block are unintentional?

Comment: Yeah sorry my formatting is terrible. Also some of the lines of code are not supposed to be split into 2 lines